# SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Group
(
group_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
date_joined DATE NOT NULL,
refersTo VARCHAR2(40),
CONSTRAINT g_group_name_pk PRIMARY KEY(group_name),
CONSTRAINT g_refersTo_fk FOREIGN KEY(refersTo) REFERENCES Artist(artistic_name));
```

This gives "ERROR at line 1: ORA-00903: invalid table name":

```
CREATE TABLE Group
             *
```

Comment: _Is_ `Group` a valid table name? Perhaps you need some escaping, like `"Group"`?

Comment: Yeah I did with 'Group' but I got same error

Comment: Group is a reserved word in Oracle. See here for the full list: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14354/appb.htm

Comment: `Group` is a reserved word in Oracle (and basically every other database).  Choose a different name for your table.  Perhaps `groups`?

Comment: Thanks :) I solved. It seems it's not allowed to use Group

Answer (score 4):

Since Group is a reserved word you have to escape it with `"`. Give the following a try or rename your table to something else:

```
CREATE TABLE "Group"
(
group_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
date_joined DATE NOT NULL,
refersTo VARCHAR2(40),
CONSTRAINT g_group_name_pk PRIMARY KEY(group_name),
CONSTRAINT g_refersTo_fk FOREIGN KEY(refersTo) REFERENCES Artist(artistic_name));
```

Comment: Double quotes cause all sorts of trouble in applications.  Why not just choose a different/better name?

Comment: True, it's better to use different name.